# Сработка скрипта бекапа при обновлении\выдаче сертификатов Let's Encrypt

Tags: резервное-копирование, скрипт, hook

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как то сделать сработку скрипта бекапа(bash) именно при успешной выдаче\обновлении ключей и сертификата certbot-ом? Да, я знаю, что можно через crontab сделать бекапы раз в n дней, но надо сделать так, что бы на резервном сервере всегда были актуальные сертификаты и ключи.

Comment: В certbot для такого есть renewal-hooks

Comment: В acme.sh для этого есть --post-hook --renew-hook и --deploy-hook

Comment: А вы не могли бы подсказать, как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт нужно положить в /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy